# Alternative to df.iterrows() for joining two Postgres tables and computing features

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pandas

I have a dataframe (`game_df`) and a Postgres table (`team_stats_1970_2017`).

`game_df` consists of a few thousand rows with data like this...

```
      season_yr home_team visitor_team  home_team_runs  visitor_team_runs
0         2017       ARI          SFG               6                  5
1         2017       ARI          SFG               4                  8
2         2017       ARI          SFG               8                  6
3         2017       ARI          SFG               9                  3
4         2017       ARI          CLE               7                  3
5         2017       ARI          CLE              11                  2
6         2017       ATL          LAD               2                  3
```

`team_stats_1970_2017` would have this corresponding data

```
   team season_yr  r_per_g pa      ab    b_r  b_h   b2   b3   b_hr
0  ARI      2017     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220  
1  ATL      2017     4.52  6216.0  5584  732  1467  289  26   165       
2  CLE      2017     5.05  6234.0  5511  818  1449  333  29   212       
3  LAD      2017     4.75  6191.0  5408  770  1347  312  20   221       
4  SFG      2017     3.94  6137.0  5551  639  1382  290  28   128
```

As an example, for row 1 of `game_df`, the code selects the "ARI" and "SFG" data from `team_stats_1970_2017` in Postgres and creates features from this.  This is then repeated for the rest of the rows within `game_df`.

I am currently using `df.iterrows`, but I am noticing it is quite slow as I am only testing a small piece of my data and it is still taking a while.  Would anyone have a better/faster alternative for this?

```
features = []
results = []
for index,row in game_df.iterrows():
        import psycopg2 as pg2
        connect = pg2.connect(login)
        cursor=connect.cursor()

        year, t1, t2, p1, p2 = row
        p1, p2 = map(int, [p1, p2]) 
        feature1 = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM team_stats_1970_2017 WHERE team = (%s) and season_yr = (%s)",(t1,year))
        feature1 = list(cursor.fetchone()[2::])
        feature2 = cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM team_stats_1970_2017 WHERE team = (%s) and season_yr = (%s)",(t2,year))
        feature2 = list(cursor.fetchone()[2::])
        feature = np.array(feature2) - np.array(feature1)

        ## Calculate result of game 
        if (p2 - p1) > 0:
            result = 1
        else:
            result = 0

        features.append(feature)
        results.append(result)
```

Comment: Sounds like you're just trying to do some sort of merge between dataframes. Use [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), or take a look at [this documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html). Can't really help you much beyond that without seeing the data, but there is *usually* an alternative to iterating through a dataframe.

Comment: Sorry about that, what is the most efficient way of showing you the Postgre table?

Comment: in a similar way as you showed your `game_df`. I'd suggest converting it to a normal `pandas` dataframe for your application, it would make it easier for you I think

Comment: ok let me do that real quick, first time posting a question on here while a database is included in the code so a bit new to this all

Comment: updated it with what would be pulled based on the info in game_df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way a bit easier to understand but using `merge` as @sacul's solution. I would create two dataframes `df_visitor` and `df_home` with the values from `team_stats_1970_2017`, for each row and for the team in the columns `'visitor_team'` and `'home_team'` respectively, such as:

```
df_visitor = (game_df[['season_yr','visitor_team']].rename(columns={'visitor_team':'team'})
                                                   .merge(team_stats_1970_2017, how='left'))

df_home = (game_df[['season_yr','home_team']].rename(columns={'home_team':'team'})
                                             .merge(team_stats_1970_2017, how='left'))
```

and you get for example for `df_home`:

```
   season_yr team  r_per_g      pa    ab  b_r   b_h   b2  b3  b_hr
0       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
1       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
2       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
3       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
4       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
5       2017  ARI     5.01  6224.0  5525  812  1405  314  39   220
6       2017  ATL     4.52  6216.0  5584  732  1467  289  26   165
```

For each row, it's the value from `team_stats_1970_2017` associated to the team in `game_df` at the same row int he column `'home_team'`.

Now to add the difference at the original dataframe `game_df` you can do:

```
# first get the lists of columns you want to add
col_features = team_stats_1970_2017.columns[2:]
game_df[col_features] = df_visitor[col_features] - df_home[col_features]
```

and finally to add the column result, you can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
game_df['results'] = np.where(game_df['visitor_team_runs'] > game_df['home_team_runs'], 1, 0) 
# meaning if p2 > p1 then 1 else 0 as in your code I think
```

Comment: This makes a lot more sense to me, thank you very much!  Last thing though, how would you go about saving this new `game_df` with our calculated features?  Ideally like I had before in my code where I could just append each row to a list.  The only thing that comes to mind for me is itterows, ha!

Comment: @CamG not sure I understand what you want to do. At the end of the code above, you have the new columns with all the calculated value in `game_df`. If you would like better a "list" with all the values, you can still do: `features = (df_visitor[col_features] - df_home[col_features]).values` which is an numpy array, is it what you want?

Comment: I think that would do it! I’m on my phone so can’t check right now, but going to give you the answer. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if you can get your `team_stats_1970_2017` as a `pandas` dataframe, then you can apply 2 merges: one on `home_team` and `season_yr`, and one on `visitor_team` and `season_yr`:

```
merged_df = (game_df.merge(team_stats_1970_2017,
                           left_on=['home_team', 'season_yr'],
                           right_on=['team', 'season_yr'])
             .merge(team_stats_1970_2017, left_on=['visitor_team', 'season_yr'],
                    right_on=['team', 'season_yr'],
                    suffixes=['_home', '_visitor'])
             .drop(['team_visitor', 'team_home'], axis=1))

>>> merged_df
   season_yr home_team visitor_team  home_team_runs  visitor_team_runs  \
0       2017       ARI          SFG               6                  5   
1       2017       ARI          SFG               4                  8   
2       2017       ARI          SFG               8                  6   
3       2017       ARI          SFG               9                  3   
4       2017       ARI          CLE               7                  3   
5       2017       ARI          CLE              11                  2   
6       2017       ATL          LAD               2                  3   

   r_per_g_home  pa_home  ab_home  b_r_home  b_h_home      ...       b3_home  \
0          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
1          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
2          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
3          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
4          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
5          5.01   6224.0     5525       812      1405      ...            39   
6          4.52   6216.0     5584       732      1467      ...            26   

   b_hr_home  r_per_g_visitor  pa_visitor  ab_visitor  b_r_visitor  \
0        220             3.94      6137.0        5551          639   
1        220             3.94      6137.0        5551          639   
2        220             3.94      6137.0        5551          639   
3        220             3.94      6137.0        5551          639   
4        220             5.05      6234.0        5511          818   
5        220             5.05      6234.0        5511          818   
6        165             4.75      6191.0        5408          770   

   b_h_visitor  b2_visitor  b3_visitor  b_hr_visitor  
0         1382         290          28           128  
1         1382         290          28           128  
2         1382         290          28           128  
3         1382         290          28           128  
4         1449         333          29           212  
5         1449         333          29           212  
6         1347         312          20           221  

[7 rows x 21 columns]
```

You can then use this `merged_df` to calculate features. For example (since it seems you want your features as `np.arrays`), to calculate the difference between `pa_home` and `pa_visitor` (this is just a dummy example):

```
>>> (merged_df['pa_home'] - merged_df['pa_visitor']).values
array([ 87.,  87.,  87.,  87., -10., -10.,  25.])
```

Comment: yup you got it, I should have explained this better in my initial question, but how would be go about finishing the rest of the code and creating features from this merged dataframe?  Ie this section of my code `feature = np.array(feature2) - np.array(feature1)`

Comment: See my edits, I'm not exactly sure what you're going for, but you can perform fast calculations on the columns

Comment: I see what you are saying, thanks for helping me with this!  I might just stick with what I have now though since it just seems to be a little cleaner/easier to understand.

Comment: Your call! I hope it helped at least a little. Good luck!